# Is there any USB Network Adapter available for Mac that works with Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, big-sur

My MacBook 14's wifi sometimes doesn't connect with my router or my mobile hotspot. I bought a USB WiFi adapter but I couldn't find its drivers for macOS Big Sur 11.1.

I searched the internet but couldn't find any product that is compatible with macOS Big Sur 11.1. Does someone know if there area ny USB Wifi Adapters that are compatible with macOS 11.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPLink has many to choose from, eg.

- [Archer T3U Plus](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-adapter/archer-t3u-plus/)

The downside, is they don’t even sign their drivers or installer and force you to relax security on Catalina, but they seem to have the newest drivers even though they haven’t said explicitly they support Big Sur. Be sure you can return them until they support Big Sur officially if you are on a tight budget or can’t pre-test them.

Comment: This product doesn't support big Sur :(

Comment: Oh no @TahaMalik - I saw 10.11 and my brain made that 11. I’ve edited one with much more recent drivers.